# Using Properties.Settings.Default as an argument for DisplayName

Tags: c#, constants, properties.settings

I am attempting to store values for a displayName attribute from a setting held in the app.config file.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DisplayName(Properties.Settings.Default.field2Name)]
```

This does not work because it must be a constant value, which Properties.Settings.Default clearly is not. Is there any simple way to get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `DisplayName` property is virtual, you could do something like that:

```
public class DisplayNameSettingsKeyAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    private readonly string _settingsKey;

    public DisplayNameSettingsKeyAttribute(string settingsKey)
    {
        _settingsKey = settingsKey;
    }

    public string SettingsKey
    {
        get { return _settingsKey; }
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get { return (string)Properties.Settings.Default[_settingsKey]; }
    }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
[DisplayNameSettingsKey("field2Name")]
```

Comment: That is a great solution. Thanks!