# MVC DataAnnotation DisplayName not working for virtual item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Entity class which included an virtual list which is a link to another class:

```
        public virtual Employee Employee1 { get; set; }
```

So in Edit page I have my item with label Employee1 when I wanted "My Employee" so in my DataAnnotation class I add

```
[DisplayName("My Employee")]
public virtual Employee Employee1 { get; set; }
```

But it is not working yet. Other items in DataAnnotation class work well.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405937/using-properties-settings-default-as-an-argument-for-displayname

Comment: According to an answer from Joshua Hayes ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555759/wondering-why-displayname-attribute-is-ignored-in-labelfor-on-an-overridden-prop ) the use of DisplayAttribute instead of DisplayNameAttribute takes care of this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was not working because visual studio when create view automatically, for foreign keys use Labelfor instead of DisplaynameFor like below:

```
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee1.LastName, "Employee1")
```

So read that value from second parameter instead of DataAnnotation so We need to change it to:

```
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee1.LastName, "My Employee")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give DataAnnotation in original class property. If you give DataAnnotation  to virtual property, it doesnt work. I tested. But If you give DataAnnotation  to property in original class. It works.

Such as:

```
public partial class Languages
{
   DataAnnotation  here
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}



public partial class Categories
{

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string FKLanguageCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Order { get; set; }

     DataAnnotation Not Here
    public virtual Languages Languages { get; set; }
 }
```